# Swagger, PHP variables in comments, for loop

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-php

I'm new to swagger, and need some help ;)
everything is set up, and works ..

my controllers is set up automatically with a for loop, is there a way to

```
$services = array(
    "Users",
    "Radios",
    "Stations",
    "UserAccess",
    "Scratchs",
    "Members",
    "Pages",
);

$api = $this->app["controllers_factory"];

foreach($services as $service) {
        $service = strtolower($service);

        /**
         * @SWG\Resource(basePath="/api/v1",resourcePath="/$service")
         */

        /**
         * @SWG\Api(
         *   path="/$service/{id}",
         *   description="Operations on $service", 
         *   @SWG\Operation(
         *      method="GET", 
         *      summary="Find a $service",
         *      nickname="get$service",
         *      type="array", items="$ref:$service",
         *      @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=404, message="$service not found"),
         *      @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=200, message="$service found")
         *   )
         * )
         */
        $api->get('/'.$service, $service.".controller:get");


}
```

the swagger output look like this ..

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
    "apis": [
        {
            "path": "/$service",
            "description": "Operations on $service"
        }
    ]
}
```

is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: Look at the response ;) ... it works -- but do not use the variable and do not work with the for loop ..

Comment: is there a way to registrate the swg annotations via. PHP code instead of comments?

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Doctrine annotations (which swagger-php uses) are not supported.
You've got 2 options (I'll use swagger-php v2 annotations but the principal also applies to v1.x):

**One operation with a "variable" path** ( *not* recommended )

```
/**
 * @SWG\Get(
 *   path="/{service}/{id}",
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="service",
 *       in="path",
 *       type="string", 
 *       enum={"users","radios","stations","useraccess","scratchs","members","pages"}
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Parameter(name="id",in="path", type="integer"),
 *   @SWG\Response(response=200, description="Found")
 * )
 */
```

**Generating the annotations from code** ( recommended )

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
$swagger = \Swagger\scan('path/to/project');

$services = array(
    "Users",
    "Radios",
    "Stations",
    "UserAccess",
    "Scratchs",
    "Members",
    "Pages",
);

$api = $app["controllers_factory"];

foreach($services as $service) {
        $name = strtolower($service);
        $path = '/'.$name.'/{id}';

        $swagger->paths[$path] = new Swagger\Annotations\Path([
            'path' => $path, 
            'get' =>  new Swagger\Annotations\Get([
                'description' => "Find ".$service,
                'responses' => [
                    new Swagger\Annotations\Response(['response' => 200, 'description'=> $service." found"])
                ]
            ])
        ]);

        $api->get('/'.$service, $service.".controller:get");

}
$swagger->validate();
echo $swagger;
```

Comment: Hello @bob, it works great thanks alot, .. my only problem now is to mix the "comment" way and the code way, is that not possible? my swagger models is made from the comments and the services is registrated like in your code example, but when I ref to a model type="user" it will be undefined. is there a workaround for this?